# Need help searching for a word in a sentence in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, sentence

I hope you're all having a great day. I was hoping i could get some assistance with my project code. Basically a sentence "FADED IN FADED OUT." is type in when prompted and then a search word "FADED" is typed in and the code is executed to see if the word "FADED" is in the sentence and if it is it will say "x Match(es) Found" and if not "No Match(es) Found". Well when I compile and run it gives me a "line 65: Runtime exception at 0x00400098: address out of range 0x00000000" error and there are multiple lines that have this error. Would anyone be able to assist me with this? I have been trying to do it the past 3 days and finally broke for some help... If you have any questions please let me know!

```
.data

str: .space 100                 # Pre Allocate space for the input sentence
input: .space 30                # Pre Allocate space for the input sentence 
ins: .asciiz "Please enter a sentence: "    # string to print sentence
seek: .asciiz "Please enter a word: "       # string to print sentence 
nomatch: .asciiz "No Match(es) Found"           
found: .asciiz " Match(es) Found"
newline: .asciiz "\n"               # string to print newline

.text

li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
la $a0, ins     # move str into a0
syscall         # syscall 

li $a1, 100     # allocate space for the string
la $a0, str     # load address of the input string
li, $v0, 8      # read string input from user
syscall         # issue a system call

move $t9, $a0       # move string to t5

li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
la $a0, seek        # move str into a0
syscall         # syscall 

la $a0, input       # load address of the input string
li $a2, 30      # allocate space for the string
li, $v0, 8      # read string input from user
syscall         # issue a system call

move $t8, $a0       # move string to t8
la $s5, input       # create space for the input word we are looking for in s5

wloop:          # loop to allocate space for the word we are looking for to a register
lb $t0, 0($t8)      # load first character into t0
beqz $t0, sentence  # branch to sentence loop if null character
sb $t0, 0($s5)      # store the current character into current address of s5
addi $t8, $t8, 1    # add one to t8 to move to next character
addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to the next allocated space
j wloop         # jump back to wloop

la $s4, str     # create space for the input sentence

sentence:       # loop to allocate space for the word we are looking for into a register
lb $t0, 0($t9)      # load first character into t0
beqz $t0, resetsen  # branch to check loop if null character
sb $t9, 0($s4)      # store the current character into current address of s4
addi $t9, $t9, 1    # add one to t9 to move to next character
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s5 to move to the next allocated space
j sentence      # jump back to sentence

resetsen:
li $s4, 0       # reset sentence back to 0 (first character)

resetword:
li $s5, 0       # reset word we are looking for back to 0 (first character)

check:
lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
beq $t1, 46, quit   # branch to QUIT if period found
bne $t1, 70, nextword   # if t1 != t0 branch to nextword
beq $t1, 70, checkword  # branch to found if t1 = f

nextword:       # loop to get to the next word
lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character to t1
beq $t1, 46, quit   # branch to quit if period found
bne $t1, 32, increment  # if current character is not a spaace branch to increment
beq $t1, 32, plusone    # if current character is a space branch to plusone
increment:      # increment procedure
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
j nextword      # jump to nextword
plusone:        # plusone procedure
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
j resetword     # jump to check

checkword:
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for a)
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for d)
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for e)
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
addi $s5, $s5, 1    # add one to s5 to move to next character
lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1
lb $t0, 0($s5)      # load current character of sentence to t0
bne $t1, $t0, increment # if t0 != t1 branch to increment (looking for d)
addi $t2, $t2, 1    # add one to t2 which counts occurences
j resetword

quit:
beqz $t2, exit      # if t2 = 0 branch to exit
li $v0, 1       # syscall to print integer
move $a0, $t2       # move str into a0
syscall         # syscall 
li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
la $a0, found       # move found into a0
syscall         # syscall 
j endprogram

exit:
li $v0, 4       # syscall to print string
la $a0, nomatch     # move nomatch into a0
syscall         # syscall 

endprogram:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: Which line is line 65? Presumably it uses a bad pointer. Work your way backwards to see why that pointer doesn't have the correct value. Also, use a debugger to single step the code.

Comment: Unlikely. More likely is `lb $t1, 0($s4)      # load current character of sentence to t1` because you use `$s4` as a pointer there but you zeroed it earlier: `li $s4, 0       # reset sentence back to 0 (first character)`. You might want to do `la $s4, str` instead.

Comment: Use the debugger to single step the code and see where it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I don't really know how to check this struggling really hard in my class :l

Answer (score 1):

You've got some good structure in places.

However, in a number of places the comments don't match the code (e.g. you're doing a bunch of cut-n-paste). And, while I realize you're just starting out, a lot of your sidebar comments just regurgitate the asm instruction. (e.g.):

```
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # add one to s4 to move to next character
```

It would help you with your understanding if the comments followed the algorithm:

```
addi $s4, $s4, 1    # point to next character
```

Another issue is that `checkloop:` should actually contain a loop rather than a fixed number of `bne` insts.

Aside from some of the issues mentioned by others in the top comment block, one big one is that you're resetting the sentence/string pointer. What you really need is another pointer [incremented by one] that remembers "where you left off" in the sentence and restart the inner loop from that (i.e. `checkloop:`)

Although I tried to retain as much of your code as I could, I had to refactor it quite a bit. One "trick" I used was to create a function that prompts the user, reads in the buffer, and then converts periods and newlines to spaces [this makes the scanning loop much easier]

Anyway, here it is [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
str:        .space      100         # space for sentence
input:      .space      30          # space for word to scan for

ins:        .asciiz     "Please enter a sentence: "
seek:       .asciiz     "Please enter a word: "
nomatch:    .asciiz     "No Match(es) Found"
found:      .asciiz     " Match(es) Found"
newline:    .asciiz     "\n"
quo1:       .asciiz     "'"
quo2:       .asciiz     "'\n"

    .text
    .globl  main
# registers:
#   t0 -- current char from string
#   t1 -- current char from word
#   t4 -- space char
#   t5 -- pointer to current char in word to scan for
#   t6 -- pointer to current char in string for given pass
#   t7 -- pointer to start of scan in string ("where we left off")
#   t8 -- word match count
main:
    # read sentence
    la      $a0,ins                 # prompt
    la      $a1,100                 # length of buffer
    la      $a2,str                 # buffer address
    jal     rdstr

    # read scan word
    la      $a0,seek                # prompt
    la      $a1,30                  # length of buffer
    la      $a2,input               # buffer address
    jal     rdstr

    la      $t7,str                 # pointer to first char in string
    li      $t8,0                   # zero the match count

strloop:
    move    $t6,$t7                 # start scan where we left off in string
    la      $t5,input               # start of word to scan for
    li      $t4,0x20                # get ascii space

wordloop:
    lbu     $t0,0($t6)              # get char from string
    addiu   $t6,$t6,1               # advance pointer within string

    lbu     $t1,0($t5)              # get char from scan word
    addiu   $t5,$t5,1               # advance pointer within scan word

    bne     $t0,$t1,wordfail        # char mismatch? if yes, fly
    bne     $t1,$t4,wordloop        # at end of scan word? if no, loop

    addi    $t8,$t8,1               # increment match count

wordfail:
    addiu   $t7,$t7,1               # advance starting point within string
    lbu     $t0,0($t7)              # get next char in sentence
    bnez    $t0,strloop             # end of sentence? if no, loop

    beqz    $t8,exit                # any match? if no, fly
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall to print integer
    move    $a0,$t8                 # print match count
    syscall

    li      $v0,4                   # syscall to print string
    la      $a0,found               # move found into a0
    syscall
    j       endprogram

exit:
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall to print string
    la      $a0,nomatch             # move nomatch into a0
    syscall

endprogram:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# rdstr -- read in and clean up string (convert '.' and newline to space)
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- prompt string
#   a1 -- buffer length
#   a2 -- buffer address
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- current character
#   t1 -- newline char
#   t2 -- ascii period
#   t3 -- ascii space
rdstr:
    # prompt user
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall to print string
    syscall

    # get the string
    move    $a0,$a2                 # get buffer address
    li      $v0,8                   # read string input from user
    syscall                         # issue a system call

    li      $t1,0x0A                # get ascii newline
    li      $t2,0x2E                # get ascii dot
    li      $t3,0x20                # get ascii space

    # clean up the string so the matching will be easier/simpler
rdstr_loop:
    lbu     $t0,0($a0)              # get character

    beq     $t0,$t1,rdstr_nl        # fly if char is newline
    beq     $t0,$t2,rdstr_dot       # fly if char is '.'

rdstr_next:
    addiu   $a0,$a0,1               # advance to next character
    j       rdstr_loop

rdstr_dot:
    sb      $t0,0($a0)              # replace dot with space
    j       rdstr_loop

rdstr_nl:
    sb      $t3,0($a0)              # replace newline with space

    j       rdstr_done              # comment this out to get debug print

    # debug print the cleaned up string
    li      $v0,4                   # output string
    la      $a0,quo1                # output a quote
    syscall
    move    $a0,$a2                 # output the cleaned up string
    syscall
    la      $a0,quo2
    syscall

rdstr_done:
    jr      $ra                     # return
```